# Delphi: two dimensional array to one dimensional array

Tags: delphi

I have a two dimensional array. In a for loop, I want to do like this

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var i : integer;
    arr : array[0..2, 0..1] of integer;
    tmpArr : array[0..1] of integer;
begin
  arr[0, 0] := 0;
  arr[0, 1] := 92;

  arr[1, 0] := 1;
  arr[1, 1] := 75;

  arr[2, 0] := 2;
  arr[2, 1] := 70;

  for i := 0 to 2 do
    tmpArr := arr[i];

end;
```

But it says Incompatible types. I think arr[i] and tmpArr are both one dimensional array, each have two elements, aren't they?

Comment: What you really want here is a typed constant so you can get the data populated at compile time rather than runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays that "look identical" are not assignment compatible in Delphi.
You need to declare a type:

```
type
  TSomeArray = array[0..1] of integer;
var
  i: integer;
  arr: array[0..2] of TSomeArray;
  tmpArr: TSomeArray;
begin
  arr[0, 0] := 0;
  arr[0, 1] := 92;

  arr[1, 0] := 1;
  arr[1, 1] := 75;

  arr[2, 0] := 2;
  arr[2, 1] := 70;

  for i := 0 to 2 do
    tmpArr := arr[i];
end;
```